# What is wrong with my code? I can't compile it

Tags: c++

So the objective of this program is to display the initials of a name typed in by the user. So if I type James Issac Newton, it should give me JIN. I tried compiling my code in the terminal using g++ -Wall -o name name.cpp but it wouldn't compile. What exactly am I doing wrong??

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  char name[100];
   gets(name);
   char a,b,c;
   cin>>name;
   a=name[0];
   int x;
   for (int i=0;i<=strlen(name);i++)
       {
            if (name[i]==" ")
                  {
                     b=name[i+1];
                     x=i;
                     break;
                  }

       }
   for (int j=x;j<=strlen(name);j++)
         {
             if (name[j]==" ")
                   {
                c=name[j+1];
                   }
         }


        cout<<a<<b<<c;

        return 0;   


        }
```

Compiler error messages:
The name of my file is acro.cpp acro.cpp:

```
In function âint main()â:  
acro.cpp:8:2: warning: âchar* gets(char*)â is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/stdio.h:638) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
acro.cpp:8:11: warning: âchar* gets(char*)â is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/stdio.h:638) [-Wdeprecated-declarations] acro.cpp:13:29: error: âstrlenâ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: What does the compiler tell you is wrong?

Comment: At a guess I'd say that it's complaining about `strlen`. You're including `<string>` but you need to include `<string.h>` to get `strlen`.

Comment: Also, `strlen` returns a `size_t` which is unsigned, but you're comparing it to an `int` which is signed.

Comment: NOTE : The name of my file is acro.cpp 
acro.cpp: In function âint main()â:
acro.cpp:8:2: warning: âchar* gets(char*)â is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/stdio.h:638) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
acro.cpp:8:11: warning: âchar* gets(char*)â is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/stdio.h:638) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
acro.cpp:13:29: error: âstrlenâ was not declared in this scope

Answer (score 3):

Since you declared:

```
   char name[100];
```

then `name[i]` (if `i` is a valid index) is a `char`. But `" "` is *not* a character literal, but a string; you should code

```
   if (name[j]==' ')
```

BTW, you should read more about C++ (and its [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)) and consider declaring

```
 std::string name;
```

and adapting the rest of your program to make that work. BTW, compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`) and learn how to use the debugger (`gdb`)

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, the compiler told you what's wrong, but you forgot to provide that information. My compiler says

```
‘strlen’ was not declared in this scope
```

because you forgot to include the header `<cstring>` that defines it.

Then it says

```
ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer
```

That's a bit trickier to interpret; it refers to this

```
if (name[i]==" ")
```

where you try to compare a character (which converts to an integer) with a string (which converts to a pointer). Instead, compare with another character:

```
if (name[i]==' ')
             ^ ^
```

Once it compiles, get rid of `gets(name);`. It does the same thing as `cin >> name;`, but is (perhaps) even more dangerous. Then consider using `std::string` rather than a C-style `char` array; that way, your program won't explode if you enter more than 100 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from compiler errors you have done one more mistake :-

```
   gets(name);
   char a,b,c;
   cin>>name;
```

second cin would overide first value you have entered using gets.